# Encrypting a Wifi Hotspot

Tags: wifi-hotspot

I was able to set up a wifi hotspot using the following:

`nmcli dev wifi hotspot ifname wlp8s0 ssid adam password "password"`

But how do I encrypt the password and select the cipher that is used?

Looking at the file

```
/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/hotspot.nmconnection
```

It is almost identical to the one corresponding to the wifi connection provided by my ISP, but when I connect to the hotspot with another computer, it says that it is unencrypted.

Also, I am unable to connect to the hot spot with any of my android devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for way to utilize WPA/WPA2 encryption?
While looking into this for you, I found the following article:
https://medium.com/@anooppoommen/create-a-wifi-hotspot-on-linux-29349b9c582d

This article describes how to setup a simple configuration file that will allow you to utilize encryption with your hotspot.

Comment: Thanks it turns out that I just didn't have a sufficiently large password and it worked as soon as I gave it a larger one. Still unable to connect any android devices, but I think that might be because I haven't set up a DHCP service, and  it can't assign anymore than one IP